# how to display custom quotation marks with sifr?

Tags: sifr, quotes, quotations

I have some text and quotation marks around it, but I want each of them to be a different font to be replaced by sifr. The problem is that the quotes need to go exactly around the text, but the text once turned into an  tag becomes a block and the text isn't shaped necessarily like a rectangle. I thought about having the quotes be background images of the replaced text, but only safari 3 supports multiple background images. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Flash provides enough control over text elements to get this as precise as you'd like.